# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, openlayers

I am trying to deploy a website with a basic express server(inexperienced with it obviously) when I use a node dev server it works fine but when I use `node server.js` i get this error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

So I have a main.js with imports as follows:

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import { defaults as defaultControls } from 'ol/control';
```

I have my basic server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3003;

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname));


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
```

Start script

```
 "start": "node server.js",
```

and webpack config

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: './main.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    port: 3003,
    clientLogLevel: 'none',
    stats: 'errors-only'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([{from: 'data', to: 'data'}]),
    new HtmlPlugin({
      template: './frontend/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

folder structure

```
frontend -index.html
         -page2.html 
main.js
package.json
webpack
...
```

Comment: Whenever one uses Webpack and a mix of both CommonJS and ES6 module syntax it doesn't usually go well. You can start by adding `"type"="module"` to you `package.json` file, but that will likely blow up your ` = require()` calls.

Comment: Okay thanks, would you recommend just refactoring it to be commonJS? or maybe some kind of loader like Babel?

Comment: You're already using a loader - its called Webpack. Since you are using Webpack, I would stick with commonJS and make sure you set the `"type"="commonjs" in `package.json`

Comment: I Appreciate the advice however the import statements will still be dysfunctional. Any idea on how to by pass this?